# Python - Decode using utf-8-sig?

Tags: python, json, utf

I'm working with a REST API and I can't seem to return the JSON data. Python returns Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig).

```
 r = wcapi.get("products")
 text = r.json().decode("utf-8-sig", errors="replace")
 print (text)
```

I tried this but got an error - bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.

```
 text = json.load(codecs.decode(r.text, 'utf-8-sig'))
```

How can I print the JSON data? Ideally, I want to avoid r.text().

Comment: `.json()` and `.text` already decodes. Use the `.content`  directly

Comment: Ah no luck! .content() won't decode anything because of the UTF-8-Sig!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the finished code to interact with the WooCommerce REST API without having any UTF-8-sig issues. :)

```
# WC API (secret keys) defined in a seperate statement.
# Get a response with all the products.
response = wcapi.get("products")
response2 = response.text
text = response2.encode('utf8')[3:].decode('utf8')
# Transform json input to python objects
info = json.loads(text)

# Loop across response.
# Gets the product ID using the SKU
for d in info:
    if d['sku'] == "SKU-CODE":
        print ("Found a match!)
        break
```